# Django, let user build his own table and data structure

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

got an hard question maybe, can't find anything apparently on google, still searching for it.
In any case i'm trying to build up a form with about 40 fields.
- 20 of these fields are simple CharText fields
- 10 of these fields are simple DateTime fields
- 10 remaining fields are my dilemma.
For these last 10 field id like to let the user who's compiling the form, the possibility to:
- decide the structure of the table ( like: 3 columns.  'col1'      'col2'      'col3' 
 or 5 columns if he needs to);
- after adding the columns that he needs, he may also add new entries to the previous table.

I'll post the model base structure.
( blank lines after '=' means that i don't know how to fill )
I need to let the user build his own structure.
I may build the columns myself, but it's better to let him create them by choosing their own structure.

```
class Incarico(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nr_sinistro = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    nr_polizza = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    appuntamento_danno = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    note_pubbliche = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    note_private = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    sinistro = models.DateField(default=None)
    incarico = models.DateField(default=None)
    perizia = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    pl = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    codifiche = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    studio = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    impiegata = 
    perito = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    perito_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    accertatore = 
    revisore = 
    contatto = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    contatto_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    sopralluogo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    sopralluogo_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    interloc = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    interloc_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    evasione = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    evasione_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    mandante = 
    agenzia = 
    ispettorato = 
    ramo = 
    liquidatore = 
    assicurato = 
    amministratore = 
    broker = 
    danneggiati = 
    tipologia_sinistro =
    data_incarico = models.DateField(default=None)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=None)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can create generic fields like Charfield or JSONField if you are using Postgresql. Then with this generic fields create a validator, before and after the construction of the model.

For example you can create a JSONField and save something like this:

```
{
   "field": "CharField",
   "value": "This is a example text",
}
```

or

```
{
    "field" "DateField",
    "value": "MM/DD/YYYY"
}
```

In this way you can create the instance of the field using the name of *field* in runtime.

If you give the possibility to users to create their own custom tables you will end with a lot of tables with different schemas. Maybe is not a good idea.

Comment: im using default sqlite3, but im going to change it into mysql

Comment: Ok, i think i'll create the table columns, and i'll let the users put data inside, thanks!!!